# sql update (help me )

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

```
tbl_indicator

grp_nbr,   sect_nbr,   indicat  
1             100          p  
2             101          s
```

```
tbl_group 

grp_id,    grp_nbr,    sect_nbr,     indicat  
333         1              100           a  
555         1              100           p  
444         2              101           s
222         2              101           y
```

Here (in `tbl_group`) grp_id is Primary Key

```
tbl_order

order_id,       grp_id
5000              333
5001              555
5002              555
5003              555
5004              444
5005              444
5006              222
```

Here (in `tbl_order`) `grp_id` is a Foreign Key to `grp_id` in `tbl_group`.

In table tbl_indiactor, for one set of grp_nbr and sect_nbr there is an indicat, for the same set of grp_nbr and sect_nbr there is a correct indicat(555,1, 100, p) and a junk indicat(333, 1, 100, a) in table tbl_group, but both these grp_id s(333, 555) are present in table tbl_orders.

Now i need to update tbl_order table in such a way that the junk grp_id s should be replaced with correct grp_id s

The output should like:

```
tbl_orders

order_id,       grp_id
5000              555
5001              555
5002              555
5003              555
5004              444
5005              444
5006              444
```

here is a small change

tbl_indicator

grp_nbr,   sect_nbr,   indicat
01            100          p
02             101          s
tbl_group

grp_id,    grp_nbr,    sect_nbr,     indicat
333         01              100           a
555         01              100           p
444         02              101           s
222          2              101           y
Here (in tbl_group) grp_id is Primary Key

the junk data(indicat) in group table (222, 22, 101, y) the grp_nbr has one character length but the grp_nbr in tbl_indicat has two character length...
how can we handle this??

Comment: Have you tried anything more than posting a question here without looking at the faq or formatting guidelines?

Comment: did i made any thing wrong?? sorry for tht....

Comment: "there is a correct indicat(333,1, 100, p) and a junk indicat(555, 1, 100, a)" - if 555 is the junk group, then why does your desired output replace 333 with 555?  Your desired output also replaces 222 with 444.  It looks like you consider 222 and 333 to be old records, or "junk", because their indicat field does not match the indicat field of their related tbl_indicator record.  correct?

Comment: sorry tht was a mistake... i edited my post now...thnx..

Comment: yes, i  want that old(junk) records to be replace with correct ones in tbl_orders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, figure out which records need to be updated:

```
select *
from tbl_order o
inner join tbl_group g on
    g.grp_id = o.grp_id
inner join tbl_indicator i on
    i.grp_nbr = g.grp_nbr
    and i.sect_nbr = g.sect_nbr
where
    g.indicat != i.indicat
```

Now, modify the query to update those records with the correct grp_id.  Notice that I've added an extra join to the tbl_group table with an alias of "g2".  This will be the correct group.

```
update o set
    o.grp_id = g2.grp_id
from tbl_order o
inner join tbl_group g on
    g.grp_id = o.grp_id
inner join tbl_indicator i on
    i.grp_nbr = g.grp_nbr
    and i.sect_nbr = g.sect_nbr
inner join tbl_group g2 on
    g2.grp_nbr = i.grp_nbr
    and g2.sect_nbr = i.sect_nbr
    and g2.indicat = i.indicat
where
    g.indicat != i.indicat
```

Note that due to the inner join on tbl_group g2, the records will not be updated if there does not exist any tbl_group record where indicat matches the indicat value of its associated tbl_indicator record.

Comment: worked like a charm..... thnx a ton... trying from 2 dayz but dint find any luck...thnx a lot..