# t-sql update issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

**tbl_indicator**

```
grp_nbr,   sect_nbr,   indicat  
001234     100         p  
002345     101         s
```

**tbl_group**

```
grp_id,    grp_nbr,    sect_nbr,     indicat  
333        001987      100           a  
555        001987      100           p  
444        002987      101           s
222        02987       101           y
```

Here (in `tbl_group`) `grp_id` is the primary Key

**tbl_order**

```
order_id,       grp_id
5000            333
5001            555
5002            555
5003            555
5004            444
5005            444
5006            222
```

In `tbl_order`,  `grp_id` is a foreign Key to `grp_id` in `tbl_group`.

In table `tbl_indicator`, for one set of `grp_nbr` and `sect_nbr` there is an `indicat`, for the same set of `grp_nbr` and `sect_nbr` there is a correct `indicat` (555,1, 100, p) and a junk `indicat` (333, 1, 100, a) in table `tbl_group`, but both these `grp_id` (333, 555) are present in table `tbl_orders`.

And one more thing here is that the junk data (indicat) in group table (222, 02987, 101, y) the `grp_nbr` has one character length less than the `grp_nbr` in `tbl_indicat`. It should use something 'LIKE' operator

How can we handle this??

Now I need to update `tbl_order` table in such a way that the junk `grp_id` s should be replaced with correct `grp_id` s

The output should like:

**tbl_orders**

```
order_id,       grp_id
5000              555
5001              555
5002              555
5003              555
5004              444
5005              444
5006              444
```

I already have answer if both the column data in `tbl_indicat` and `tbl_grp` tables are same...

It was answered by 'Dr. Wily's Apprentice'

[sql update (help me )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083716/sql-update-help-me)

but how to handle if the data is different (like missing some strings in starting)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: If you cast the columns to numeric and compare them numerically, you can ignore the leading zeroes. How do you determine which are the "junk" records?

Comment: i cannot cast it to numeric b/c some of my data contains characters

Comment: and if i dont find indicat value for corresponding set of grp_nbr and sect_nbr in tbl_group and tbl_indicator tables then that rec is junk rec in tbl_group table

Comment: Also, avoid adding (Help me) in the title, and try to make the title more relevant to your problem.

Comment: This is really hard to follow with abbreviations for every word.  Please reword the question in a more verbose manner, and the answer to "which are the 'junk' records."  thx 4 teh sql

Comment: There is no way to help you here without a clear definition of your problem.  @Bojan did a great job of editing/rewriting your post but I'm not sure your text now matches the numeric examples.  For example you mention "indicat (555,1, 100, p)".  Your indicat table doesn't have four columns so what doesn't this mean?  And can you explain why you expect Order 5000 to have its grp_id=555?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE o
SET o.grp_id = g2.grp_id
FROM tbl_order AS o
INNER JOIN tbl_group AS g1
    ON g1.grp_id = o.grp_id
INNER JOIN tbl_group AS g2
    ON g2.sect_nbr = g1.sect_nbr
    AND g2.grp_nbr = '0' + g1.grp_nbr
```